# Using Scala Reflection for a plugin architecture

Tags: scala, dynamic, reflection

I'm building an application Scala that uses a plugin architecture, and I'm trying to load plugins in at runtime. Currently, my plugin loader code is:

```
import org.clapper.classutil.ClassFinder

object PluginManager extends PluginManager {
  val plugins = new mutable.HashMap[String, Plugin]()
  val pluginFolder = new File("plugins")

  def init(): Unit = {
    val pluginJars = pluginFolder.listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".jar"))
    val classpath = List(new File(".")) ++ pluginJars
    val finder = ClassFinder(classpath)
    val classes = finder.getClasses()
    val classMap = ClassFinder.classInfoMap(classes.iterator)
    val pluginsToLoad = ClassFinder.concreteSubclasses("org.narrativeandplay.hypedyn.plugins.Plugin", classMap)

    val loader = new URLClassLoader(pluginJars.map({ f => new URL(s"file:${f.getAbsolutePath}") }), ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader)

    pluginsToLoad.foreach {
      pluginString =>
        val plugin = loader.loadClass(pluginString.name).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Plugin]
        plugins += plugin.name -> plugin
    }
  }
}
```

(based on https://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/building-a-plugin-based-architecture-in-scala/).

I had to use the `URLClassLoader` because my plugin JARs weren't on the classpath when the application started

I was wondering if it's possible to use the Scala Reflection API to replace my use of the `URLClassLoader`, and if so, how should I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the runtime reflection part of the Scala reflection API to work, you will anyway need to instantiate a classloader (and then do `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(classloader)`), so I think that it's not going to simplify matters in this situation.